# R gsub word in string beginning with prefix without removing prefix

Tags: regex, r, escaping, gsub

I'm trying to use gsub to replace a word within a string (that's contained in single quotes, i.e. beginning and ending with a single quote) with a different word, that is stored in a variable. I want to keep the single quotes.

So if I start with this:

```
a <- "I am going to buy an 'apple' and a 'apple'"
repl <- "pear"
```

I want to it to end up as:

```
"I am going to buy an 'pear' and a 'pear'"
```

I've tried a few things like this below but it only ever seems to replace 'apple' and the single quotes, whereas I want to keep the single quotes.

```
a2 <- gsub("\'apple\'", repl, a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?<=` look behind and `?=` look ahead syntax in the `Perl-compatible regexps` as from `?gsub`, in which case the single quote will just act like boundary but won't be replaced:

```
gsub("(?<=\')apple(?=\')", repl, a, perl = T)
# [1] "I am going to buy an 'pear' and a 'pear'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("'([^']+)'", paste0("'", repl, "'"), a)
#[1] "I am going to buy an 'pear' and a 'pear'"
```